# Is it safe to convert a MBR flash drive to GPT?

Tags: partitioning, usb-flash-drive, mbr, gpt

I just bought a new flash drive (128GB) and I want to partition it. I have run into problems (AKA windows not recognizing a second volume if I partition it) because it is an MBR drive. Are there any drawbacks to converting my drive to a GPT so I can partition it more freely? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not recognize the second volume NOT because it is an MBR disk, but because of its SCSI Removable Medium Bit is set to 1 (and how Windows handles such drive), which is something you sort of can't change. You can't even convert such drive from MBR to GPT in the GUI Disk Management, but you can do that with `convert gpt` in `diskpart`. However, IIRC, it won't help with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If that won't help me, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you want to partition it? If it's to support different partitions for different OSes, you might be able to simply make the Windows partition the first one. Windows will ignore the second and subsequent partitions, but most other OSes (such as Linux and OS X) will handle them fine, whether the disk is GPT or MBR. If you want multiple partitions in Windows, you may not be able to do that, but maybe using folders or a virtual disk image would do the job.